# Create Customized Relationship?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

The model `user`  may have 0 or more `foo`'s and may have 0 or more `bar`'s. Here is a diagram:

[image]

**There is the following rule**:
If a user has any bar, then this implies that he has the foo with `id=1`. A user may not have foo with `id=1` without a bar. To prevent database inconsistency, there is never a row inserted in `foo_user` with `foo_id = 1`, because its already implied by the `bar_user` table.

In Laravel I can get all `foo`'s from a user like this:

```
public foos()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('App\Foo');
}
```

The problem is that because of the above rule, the `foo` with `id = 1` might be missing. Is there an easy way to customize my relationship method `foos` so that it checks, if `bar_user` exists, then add `foo` with `id=1`? I would like to get the correct foos with one query and with the relationship, so I may use this like `\App\User::whereHas('foos', ...)`

---

**This is what I tried**

The query to get all `foo`'s is

```
  \DB::table('foos')
          ->leftjoin('foo_user', 'foo.id', 'foo_user.foo_id')
          ->where('foo_user.user_id', '=', $this->id);
          ->orWhereRaw('EXISTS (select * from bar_user WHERE user_id = ?) AND foos.id = 1', [$this->id]);
```

I cannot do

```
public foos()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('App\Foo')
         ->orWhereRaw('EXISTS (select * from bar_user WHERE user_id = ?) AND foos.id = 1', [$this->id]); 
}
```

because there is an `innerjoin` in `belongsToMany` and not a `leftjoin`.

Comment: This feels like your attempt to design the "id = 1 is implied"-rule might not be the optimal choice, and now working around it makes things complicated. Relations and conditions that are designed into the datamodel itself should emerge extremely naturally, and are usually not circular (a implies b, b implies a). Assuming your rule and model is correct, I would probably just actually add that row to `foo` (trigger and/or app-logic, and you can also use triggers to check that condition). (Just my opinion though, there might be a better solution, or you might prefer your way).

Comment: @Solarflare I agree with you, in some scenarios it might be the better way to use app-logic to make sure the DB is consistence. However, in my particular situation (which is more complex then the here mentioned abstract foo/bar scenario), the design works already great. Its easier for me to jsut pay attention on fetching foos then having trouble when deleting or inserting bars/foos. I was just wondering if I could improve it by customizing the  relationship function a bit. But I guess its not possible.

Comment: I did not say it is not possible (I do not know laravel enough to say either, although I assume that is should be doable), just that it would probably (but not certainly) be clearer (from a database-design point-of-view, not laravel) to add that row directly (and of course assuming that you do not yet have a complete app that you would need to change for that).

Comment: @Solarflare I was asking at DatabaseAdministrators if there is a better database design 23 days ago: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227853/modelling-two-dependent-many-to-many-relationships and both answers said that this is a solid design

Comment: You mean `BelongsToMany` instead of `HasMany`? You would have to create your own extension of the `BelongsToMany`relationship and override the relevant methods.

Comment: Your schema with the pivot table requires a `BelongsToMany` relationship.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir oh ofc I meant `BelongsToMany` instead of `hasMany`.. sorryits late here.. I edited my questions thx for the remark